# Sketching $|z-i|= k|z-2i|$ in Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given the set $|z-i|= k|z-2i|$ when $k>0$

I don't understand how to sketch this set.

Help me please. Thank you.

............................

*edit*

From $|z-i|= k|z-2i|$

I have $\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2} = k\sqrt {x^2+(y-2)^2}$

I have $ x^2+(y-1)^2 = k^2(x^2+(y-2)^2)$

Thus, $x^2+y^2-2y+1 = k^2(x^2 +y^2-4y+4)$

Suppose $k=\frac{1}{2}$ , I have $x^2+(y-\frac{2}{3})^2 = \frac{4}{9}$

Suppose $k=1$ , I have $y=\frac{3}{2}$

Suppose $k=2$ , I have $x^2+(y-\frac{7}{3})^2 =\frac{19}{6} $

Suppose $k=3$ , I have $x^2+(y-\frac{17}{8})^2 = \frac{9}{64}$

Now, I think when I suppose $k\geq{3}$ I have circles small than $k=2$

Can I sketch this set from equation $x^2+(y-\frac{7}{3})^2 =\frac{19}{6} $ ?

Comment: Have you tried plotting a few points? Fix $k$ and find some simple values for $z$, then see what happens.

Comment: You might try looking at this as $\left|\,\frac{z-i}{z-2i}\,\right|=k$ which means that $\frac{z-i}{z-2i}=ke^{i\theta}$.

Comment: Solving for $z$ gives the parameterization $z=\frac{2ke^{i\theta}-1}{ke^{i\theta}-1}\,i$

Comment: thank you sir. @robjohn

Comment: @user1729 Thank you, could you check my edit for me.

Comment: I reopened this question since the author has added their work.

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7uCkn.png) is what these look like.

Comment: Wow! Fantastic! Thank you very much. @robjohn

Comment: Ehhh..I am not very sure about when k converge approch to 1 ex. 10000/10201 this circle greater than 3/4 .

Comment: @Zera: when $k\to1$, the circle tends to the line $y=\frac32$.

Answer (score 2):

Continue with $x^2+y^2-2y+1 = k^2(x^2 +y^2-4y+4)$ to obtain the general expression,

$$x^2+\left(y-\frac{2k^2-1}{k^2-1}\right)^2 = \left(\frac k{k^2-1}\right)^2$$

So, for any $k>0$ and $k\ne1$, the set is of a circle with center $(0,\frac{2k^2-1}{k^2-1})$ and radius $\frac k{k^2-1}$. For example, if $k=2$, the circle becomes,

$$x^2+\left(y-\frac{7}{3}\right)^2 = \left(\frac 2{3}\right)^2$$

which is sketched here, showing that the distance from $z$ to (0,i) is twice as that from $z$ to (0,2i).

[image]